# Automatic shell script launch in linux mint 20.3

Tags: linux, shell, email

I want to print pdf attachments automatically that arrive at a specific mail adress. For this purpose I have set up Filtaquilla so that pdf attachments are automatically stored in a specific folder. Further I have programmed a little shell script to print all pdf files in that folder. When started manually the script works fine. However launching the script from Filtaquilta does not work. Has anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. Filtaquilla apparently takes very long to transfer the PDFs in the folder I specified. Therefore the script did not find them. The solution was to let the script wait for 2 min (Command at beginning: sleep 120). Now everything works fine. A further note: When Filtaquilla launches a script you have to specify the absolute path when accessing a file with the script. Otherwise it will not work (from what I have seen).